# how to set focus on sheet tab in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you set focus on sheet tab in excel working book?I need to do a number of functions such as select all sheets, switch back and forth the sheet, delete, group,ungroup, is very inconvenient to use mouseclick.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows versions of Excel you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move between worksheets and holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while doing so will allow you to select multiple (adjacent) worksheets.

Comment: @ Mike Fitzpatrick that's very helpful Mike! Can I dare myself ask a related questions, is there a shortcut to ungroup the sheets grouped already and select all(instead of multiple) the sheets in one go with keyboard shortcuts?Tks!

Comment: @frog, not that I'm aware of, sorry.